# Paint game level algorithm

Tags: algorithm, tile-bitmasking

I have a game, and I have a level editor where you can build your level from blocks. Blocks positioned in cells. So blocks can have no neighbours or have one or few neighbours. My problem is that I need to put appropriate texture to block, based on block position related to another blocks. Is there some specific algorithms or methods that can help me?

I want it to update textures after adding/moving/deleting each block so it should be fast.

Levels can look like

```
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|                            | 
|             |- - - |       |
|             |- - - |       |
|                            |
|         - - - - -          |
|         |       |          |
- - - - - |       | - - - - -|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a bitmask to determine which graphic you want to use, see this article
When you have neighbouring blocks of the same kind, simple change the bitmask and this bitmask is used for drawing the Tile.
http://www.angryfishstudios.com/2011/04/adventures-in-bitmasking/